# Capybara - How to click button that is enabled by javascript while it was initialed as disabled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I have a form with only one input box and a submit button in which the submit button is disabled until the user fill in something in the text box.

Unluckily, when I check the screenshot 'form.png', the submit button is still disabled even I already fill in a value.

spec:

```
scenario 'valid', js: true do
  fill_in 'Name', with: 'Hello World'
  page.save_screenshot('form.png')
end
```

coffee/js:

```
$('#name').keyup ->
  if $('#name').val() != ''
    $('#submit').removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled')
  else
    $('#submit').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
```

haml/html:

```
= f.input :name, label: 'Name'

= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary form-btn', id: 'submit', disabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Poltergeist definitely produces the keydown/keyup events when filling in input text fields, so it sounds like your JS isn't running. Make sure you don't have any JS code that depends on features greater than ES5, since PhantomJS doesn't support that, or errors.  In test mode all your JS assets get concatenated which means an error in any one file can prevent code in other files from being evaluated. Once you have that cleaned up you should just be able to do

```
click_button 'Save'
```

Comment: "Make sure you don't have any JS code that depends on features greater than ES5, since PhantomJS doesn't support that, or errors". How can I track this?

Comment: @PirunSeng Start by making sure you have enabled `js_errors` in your Poltergeist config - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization - which will catch a lot of errors.  Beyond that make sure you aren't using `let` or `const` in the JS file being served which unfortunately will silently cause the file to be ignored. If you are you will need to rewrite and/or transpile and polyfill in order to use Poltergeist/PhantomJS

Comment: I've already had js_errors option. And I don't have either `let` or `const` in any of my JS files. But, I found this line `// https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-generatorresume` in my **form-builder.min.js**, but I believe it is commented. You might be right saying that some files might be ignored as I tried making an error code in the JS file I expected to be called, and there was no syntax error raised when I ran the spec.

Comment: @PirunSeng It's not only your own JS files that matter, it's any JS files that gets concatenated into your `application.js` file.  If you have made an intentional error in one of your JS files and you're not getting that reported, then either you don't actually have `js_errors` enabled, that files isn't actually being included, you aren't running  the test in JS mode, or you have one of the ES6 syntax usage errors that causes PhantomJS to silently fail.